# Difference between に and が for intransitive verbs

Tags: verbs, particle-に, particle-が, transitivity

What is the difference between 試験に受かる and 試験が受かる?
It seems that the first one means "to pass an exam" while the second one is more like "passing exams" (really not sure about it).

In which cases would に be used together with an intransitive verb?

Comment: 試験が受かる sounds agrammatical because the subject for the verb 受かる is not 試験 but 私/あなた/山田さんetc. so you might say 山田さんは試験に受かった but not 山田さんは試験が受かった.

Comment: I don't really understand (i know its my problem, so please bear with me). ドアが閉まります means "the door is closing" right? So why 試験が受かる can't mean something like "the exam was passed".

Comment: @OlegLevy-san The verb 'pass' in 'the exam was passed' is transitive, I guess? And the sentence is written in the passive voice, but the word 受かる is not the passive form. The subject for the verb 'to pass' is not 'the exam', while that of 'to close' in 'the door is closing' is 'the door'.

Comment: As Chocolate said, 試験が受かる is not grammatical.  Therefore, although 受ける and 受かる may look like a transitive-intransitive pair like 閉める and 閉まる, I do not think that they are really a transitive-intransitive pair.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto-san, Ah! Now I think I know what was confusing OP. そゆことね～

Comment: @Chocolate: Yeah, the question was confusing to me, but the conversation between you and OP clarified why he thought that 試験が受かる should be grammatical.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Indeed, i considered them a transitive-intransitive pair. Moreover in JMDict, 受かる and 受ける are marked as intransitive and transitive respectively. Their meanings however dont seem to match and i realize my mistake now.

How is it possible to identify those "fake" transitive-intransitive pairs?

Comment: I doubt that there are many “fake” transitive-intransitive pairs.  The only other example I managed to come up with is 分ける/分かる, where 分かる has a very different meaning (the correct pair is 分ける/分かれる).  If such pairs are really rare, then probably the easiest way is just to remember them as exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(The question was already essentially answered in comments by Chocolate and me, but I am posting an answer as an answer.)

To answer the question literally, 試験に受かる (to pass an examination) is grammatical, but 試験が受かる is not grammatical, as Chocolate stated in her comment.

But a more interesting part comes from your logic based on which you thought that 試験が受かる would be grammatical in the first place.  Although your logic was unclear to me until I read your comment in response to Chocolate’s comment, once I understood the logic, it perfectly made sense.

Your logic: The event ドアを閉める can be described from a different perspective by saying ドアが閉まる.  Similarly, it must be possible to restate 試験を受ける as 試験が受かる (*).  But there is also an expression 試験**に**受かる.  What is the difference between 試験が受かる and 試験に受かる?

Alas, the sentence marked with (*) above is false!  受ける and 受かる may look like a transitive-intransitive pair just like 閉める and 閉まる, but they are actually not, and we cannot restate 試験を受ける as 試験が受かる.  Also note that 試験を受ける (to *take* an examination) and 試験に受かる (to *pass* an examination) describe different events, and in both cases, the subject is the person who takes/passes an examination.

The only other “false” transitive-intransitive pair like 受ける and 受かる that I can think of is 分ける (to divide) and 分かる (to understand; often written as わかる).  The correct transitive-intransitive pair is 分ける and 分かれる.