# Disambiguating に and を

Tags: particle-に

その時を待っている - I will be waiting for that time

その時に待っている - "I will be waiting **for** that time" or "I will be waiting **at** that time"

The first sentence only can ever have that single translation. The second sentence, however can mean 2 things. Is there a way to disambiguate the second sentence? (apart from context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who said the second sentence has two meanings? その時**に**待っている **only** means "I will be waiting at that time *(for something else)*". What you are waiting for is not mentioned. You'll ever need this sentence only in special contexts.

～**を**待つ in Japanese means "to wait **for** ～" in English. This is something you have to remember.

Comment: そうなんですか。I thought that に can also mean "for", and hence その時に待つ can translate to wait "for" that time

Comment: @Newbie You have to keep in mind that particles don't always work as you expect as an English speaker. You have to remember which verb works with which particles. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/16270/5010

Comment: @newbie Please see this, too: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72206/5010