# Why use に instead of を in 彼に会います/連絡します

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-を

Please explain to me why に is used instead of を in these sentences

> 彼に会います
> 彼に連絡します

Is that because 会います is a transitive verb?
Please give me more detail.

Comment: There might be some historical reason but I don't think you are going to get a satisfying grammatical explanation. It's just one of those irregularities you have to learn.

Comment: Related or dup [に versus を with 会いました verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/88919)

Comment: @user3856370 What's irregular about it? Using に with intransitive verbs is just a normal thing in Japanese, no?

Comment: @Leebo I meant irregular in the sense that you expect it to the the direct object in English but that it isn't so in Japanese. Nothing more.

Comment: Indeed, English verbs like "look", "listen" and "kiss" seemed very "irregular" to me at first :)

Answer (score 4):

会います (or 会う) doesn't take を because it is an *intransitive* verb, not a *transitive* verb. Transitive verbs take を, and intransitive verbs don't.

In general, the transitivity of verbs in English and Japanese is the same in, say, 80% of the time, but there are also many exceptional cases. Just because "to meet" or "to contact" is a transitive verb in English doesn't mean that the Japanese equivalent 会う or 連絡する is transitive. There are many similar examples, and you simply have to remember them one by one. Please take a look at this list: [に vs. を in "to pass a test"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72200/5010)