# Distinction of using を/に instead of が

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-が, particle-を, transitivity

> さあ次もビーチバレーという名のウォッチング[に]勤しむぜ！- Ok, next,  lets endeavor to watch beach
>   volleyball !
>
> それにしても、人間世界はじつに物[に]あふれておるな。- That being said, the world of humans is actually overflowing with things (this one in particular に over　が just feels strange)
>
> [私は他動詞の使い方[を]本から教わった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/329/passive-transitive-verb-vs-intransitive-verb-%e4%bb%96%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e%e3%81%ae%e5%8f%97%e3%81%91%e8%ba%ab-vs-%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e8%a9%9e?noredirect=1&lq=1)-
>   I learned about transitive verbs from a book
>
> 我が豪腕[に]奪えぬ物は無し！ - There's nothing my strong arm can't steal!
>   (transitive verb for this one)

While trying to do some research I found the 3rd* sentence which feels like it's a similar use case but with を instead.

If I were forced to produce Japanese from the above English sentences, I would default to [が] in all of those brackets if I used that sentence structure. At the same time I feel like I can only interpret those sentences as if [が] were in the [] instead of [を/に].  At a glance it doesn't seem grammatically incorrect, but I don't know what meaning I am sacrificing by doing so.

Yet at the same time for something like this

> だから、もっと素直に私[に]甘えて…… - listen, be honest more honest and depend on me

In this case [が] would feel strange to me but there doesn't seem to be anything fundamentally different between 私[に]甘えて and ウォッチング[に]勤しむ / 物[に]あふれて

---

I have read [Difference between に and が for intransitive verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/difference-between-%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%8c-for-intransitive-verbs?rq=1), but i don't think my issues boil down to false” transitive-intransitive pairs.

I would appreciate any clarification, thank you.

Comment: you say: _"I found the 2rd sentence"_.  This appears to be a typo, but I can't tell -- did you mean to say "third", or "second"?

Comment: 3rd woops, I linked where i got the sentence from :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance appears to come down to the particulars of each verb, so let's look at those in turn.

#### 勤【いそ】しむ

- To work towards something, to endeavor to do something, to make oneself busy at something

This is listed as a 自動詞 in dictionaries.  As such, whatever is marked as が for this verb would be the grammatical subject -- the agent performing the action of the verb.  Since ウォッチング​**[が]【●】**​勤しむ would mean that the *watching* was *endeavoring*, and since that doesn't make any sense, we know that we can't use the が here.

As for why to use に instead, it might be helpful to think of the action of the verb from an English perspective: one *endeavors **to** do something*, or *works **toward** something*, etc.  In a similar way, 勤しむ describes an action *towards* a particular goal, so the goal takes the particle に in much the same way as a destination takes に with the verb 行【い】く.

#### 溢【あふ】れる

- To overflow, to be full of

Much as with the English verb *overflow*, the Japanese verb 溢【あふ】れる can describe **either** the action of a thing, or the state of another thing that contains the first thing.

For instance, we can say that *water **overflows** from a cup*.  Since we are using the verb to describe the water, we use が after the 水【みず】:

- カップから水​**[が]【●】**​溢れる

Alternatively, we can say that *the cup **overflows** with water*.  In this case, we are using the verb to describe the cup, so we use が after the カップ.  Moreover, the water is *causing* the cup to overflow, so we use に after the 水【みず】 to mark that cause, similar to passive verbs where に is used to indicate the causal agent:

- カップ​**[が]【●】**​水​**[に]【●】**​溢れる

#### 教【おそ】わる

- To be taught something, to learn something

Etymologically, this verb could be viewed as the passive form of 教【おし】える, *to teach something* → *to be taught something*, and thus by extension, *to learn something*.  That said, it is still a 他動詞, and thus it can take an object marked with を.

If we were to say 使い方​**[が]【●】**​教わった, it would mean that the *way of using something* had *been taught* or *learned* something.  This again doesn't make any sense -- what we want to say instead is that ***I** learned how to use something*.  Much as in this English sentence, the *I* is the subject, and the *how to use something* is the object -- so in Japanese, we mark the subject with が (or optionally は, depending on context, etc.) and we mark the direct object with を:

- 私​**[が]【●】**​使い方​**[を]【●】**​教わった

#### 奪【うば】える

- To be able to be stolen or taken by force

This is a potential verb, and these work differently.  They essentially describe a quality of a thing as *being `[VERB]`-able*.  分かる functions in a similar way -- it describes something as *being understandable*, which is why we say 何々​**[が]【●】**​分かる, marking the thing as the subject in Japanese. 
 This construction is puzzling when translated, as English uses transitive verbs in these cases, much like *understand* or *like*.

Your sample sentence describes the 物 as 奪えぬ or *being unstealable*.  In English, if we called something *unstealable* and wanted to explain that in relation to who might try to steal it, we would say it is *unstealable **by** someone*.  In Japanese, we again use に to mark the agent, similar to 溢れる above and similar to passive constructions.  If we marked the 腕 with が, we would instead be saying that the 腕 themselves are *unstealable* -- which might still be the case, but it sounds a little funny and it definitely changes the meaning.  :)

Comment: Wow thank you, this is really thorough, will be a great reference.  Regarding  "に as  causal agent", outside of Xに~られる constructs, what is the difference between using で over に in places like 物にあふれる and 腕に奪える?  Also, [under the formal definitions of に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/), i could never seem to find a good approximation of "to/towards", even though that was the most common usage when i see XにIntransative Verb.  It seems to only list physical destinations/directions (definition 3), it it technically under that umbrella? Thank you!

Comment: `カップが水に溢れる` -- ふつう、「～～が水**で**あふれる」じゃないですかね・・

Comment: @Chocolate I think the point is that that structure itself is possible, though it's not so much "full of " as "affluent in"

Comment: 「～にあふれる」は、「活気にあふれる」「やる気にあふれる」とかいうふうに使いますよね（「お風呂がお湯であふれる」とは意味が違う）。あと、「野次馬が歩道にあふれる」「目に涙があふれる」「偽ブランド品が市場にあふれる」とか。（これはあふれるものが「～に」じゃなくなる）

Comment: ＠chocolate could i extrapolate this as  both「世界が物にあふれる」and 「世界に物があふれる」being correct? Would [the world is overflowing with stuff ] vs [In this world, the stuff is overflowing]  be a good way to look at it?

Comment: @Chocolate, ふ～む、困りますね。「～に溢れて」、「～で溢れて」ググってみて比較しますと（「水」の例以外は）「に」のほうが多いように見えますが。もしかしたら物理的なものなら「で」、抽象的なものなら「に」となりますか。

Answer (score 0):

In order to know which particle to use, you have to consult the dictionary.
Different words will require different particles.

According to the dictionary, を indicates what you learn.
に indicates who teaches you.
And since 教わる means 教えてもらう, the speaker is automatically the subject.

Examples:
水泳を教わった
I learned [was taught] how to swim.

算数は上田先生に教わった
Mr. Ueda taught me arithmetic.

おそわる【教わる】教えを受ける。教えてもらう。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/教わる/#je-8504](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%95%99%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/#je-8504)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31383/meaning/m0u/おそわる/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31383/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/)
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31383/example/m0u/おそわる/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/31383/example/m0u/%E3%81%8A%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/)