# How is に used in the following sentence?

Tags: particle-に

I have the following sentence from my hero academia anime.

```
つくづく あの入試は 合理性に欠くよ｡
```

The english subtitles for the show have this as the translation "That entrance exam was definitely not rational enough."

I'm confused at how に is working here. I know that に can be used for nouns that take the copula (na adjectives) to turn them into an adverb but 合理性 isn't one of these na adjectives. I would think を or は would make more sense here. Is に perhaps acting as a substitute for は here?

I've ruled out this acting as an indirect object marker and a direction marker. From there, I'm pretty clueless as to what it's exact function is here. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Besides being a set phrase, looks to me as a syntactic match for the English "to lack in reason". Is that "in" confusing too?

Comment: @macraf Where do you see this is a set phrase?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62813/9831

Comment: When I look at the dictionary for 合理性, I see 「〜に欠ける」 given as prime usage example. Here https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%88%E7%90%86%E6%80%A7-497839 two dictionaries do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [に vs が in 君に欠けているもの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62811/%e3%81%ab-vs-%e3%81%8c-in-%e5%90%9b%e3%81%ab%e6%ac%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae)

Comment: It's off topic, but the verb 欠く often takes the particle を, unlike 欠ける taking に. Here occurs the confusion between these two.